# incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Diff<?>

Tags: java, apache-commons-lang3

I have this Java method which his used to compare data:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.Diff;

public void addChangedPositions(DiffrentResult diffrentResult , List<UpdatedPositionsData> updatedPositionsData) {
    for (Diff<?> diff : diffResult.getDiffs()) {
      UpdatedPositionsData updatedData = new UpdatedPositionsData();
      updatedData.setName(diff.getFieldName() == null ? null : diff.getFieldName());
      updatedData.setOldValue(diff.getLeft() == null ? null : diff.getLeft().toString());
      updatedData.setNewValue(diff.getRight() == null ? null : diff.getRight().toString());
      updatedPositionsData.add(updatedField);
    }    
  }
........

@Getter
@Setter
public class UpdatedPositionsData {

  private String name;
  private String oldValue;
  private String newValue;

}
```

But for this line `for (Diff<?> diff : diffResult.getDiffs()) {`

I get error:

```
incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Diff<?>
```

So I have:

```
Required type:
Object

Provided:
Diff
<?>
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

P.S unfortunately the problem is not solved.

I created this small example code:

https://github.com/rcbandit111/hateos_poc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/hateos/test/assembler/CodeLogAssembler.java#L14

Can you advise how can be fixed, please?

Comment: What does getDiffs() return?

Comment: are you sure that the parameter DiffrentResult diffrentResult is correct?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen it's returning `public List<Diff<?>> getDiffs() {`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The code you have shown us is incomplete, and markspace's attempt to reconstruct a complete example that reproduces your problem has a failed.  We can't advise a solution if we don't have sufficient information to understand what the problem is.

Comment: the issue it probably with the declaration of `DiffrentResult.getDiffs()` 
you should declare it as:
`public List<Diff<? extends SomeType>> getDiffs()` 

(replace `SomeType` with whatever you are returning)

Comment: Ummm.... I see `void addChangedPositions(DiffrentResult diffrentResult, ...` but `for (Diff<?> diff : diffResult.getDiffs())` - `diffrentResult` vs `diffResult`... Is that a typo or is `diffResult` declared in an enclosing context?  This is why you MUST reduce the issue to a [mcve] (or ensure that what you post reflects the actual code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a generic type, like `DiffResult`, but you omit its generic type in the declaration, then all methods lose their generic information. In other words, if you declare the field, variable or parameter as `DiffResult` instead of `DiffResult<WhatEverType>`, then its `getDiffs()` method doesn't return `List<Diff<?>>` but instead `List` - without any generic information.

This can be shown with a very easy example:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    List<String> strings() {
        return List.of("a", "b", "c");
    }
}
MyClass m = new MyClass(); // raw type warning ignored
List<String> strings = m.strings(); // compiler warning
for (String s : m.strings()) { // compiler error, like the one you're getting
}
```

So my guess is, you've omitted the generic type in `DiffResult`. If so, the fix is simple: add a generic type, or if you don't know or care, use the wildcard: `DiffResult<?>`.

Comment: Unfortunately I get for  ` for (DiffResult<?> diff : diffResult.getDiffs()) {`  Required type:
Object

Provided:
DiffResult
<?>

Comment: The for-loop variable should still be `Diff<?>`. It's the `diffResult` variable/parameter that needs to change from `DiffResult` to `DiffResult<?>`.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue is not fixed. I added code example into the post.

Comment: You still didn't change `DiffResult` to `DiffResult<?>` on line 13.

Answer (score 1):

So this works for me when I try it.  Check you have the right library imported, do a clean and re-build of your project, etc.  Something funny going on here.

```
public class ListReturnType<X> {
   
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      for( ListReturnType<?> x : getList() ) {
         
      }
   }
   
   public static List<ListReturnType<?>> getList() {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Check the docs, though they seem to match.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/DiffResult.html

Comment: I use this library `implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3'`

Comment: Can you advise for some solution please?

Comment: The solution has to start with >>you<< posting a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Mark has gone as far as we can go with the information that you provided.

Answer (score 1):

```java
import lombok.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.Diff;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
public class UpdatedPositionsData {

    private String name;
    private String oldValue;
    private String newValue;

    public void addChangedPositions(DiffrentResult diffResult, List<UpdatedPositionsData> updatedPositionsData) {
        for (Diff<?> diff : diffResult.getDiffs()) {
            UpdatedPositionsData updatedData = new UpdatedPositionsData();
            updatedData.setName(diff.getFieldName() == null ? null : diff.getFieldName());
            updatedData.setOldValue(diff.getLeft() == null ? null : diff.getLeft().toString());
            updatedData.setNewValue(diff.getRight() == null ? null : diff.getRight().toString());
            updatedPositionsData.add(updatedData);
        }
    }

    public interface DiffrentResult {
        List<Diff<?>> getDiffs();
    }
}
```

The code compiles without any problem, so I do not think  diffResult.getDiffs returns a list of Diff<?>> in your code.

Comment: Unfortunate the issue is not fixed. I added code example into the post.

Answer (score 1):

More specified input params (**DiffResult<?> diffResult**). I tested without complie error.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.Diff;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.DiffResult;

public class CodeLogAssembler {

  private void addNewUpdatedFields(DiffResult<?> diffResult, List<UpdatedFieldsResource> updatedFields) {
    for (Diff<?> diff : diffResult.getDiffs()) {
      UpdatedFieldsResource updatedField = new UpdatedFieldsResource();
      updatedField.setName(diff.getFieldName() == null ? null : diff.getFieldName());
      updatedField.setOldValue(diff.getLeft() == null ? null : diff.getLeft().toString());
      updatedField.setNewValue(diff.getRight() == null ? null : diff.getRight().toString());
      updatedFields.add(updatedField);
    }
  }
}
```