# Why a function call changes the type inferred in Java 8?

Tags: java, type-inference, typechecking

Example adapted from [zhihu](https://www.zhihu.com/question/518699935). The following code does not compile. But if you uncomment the highlighted line, it compiles (though with some warnings).

This problem only occurs to Java 8.

**Disclaimer: I understand that raw types should not be used at all, but I'm just curious how can it be that a single comment causes the compiler to malfunction.**

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class A {
  String title;
  Map<String, Object> data;

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public void setData(Map<String, Object> data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strs = {"hello"};
    List<A> as = Stream.of(strs).map((item) -> {
      A a = new A();
      a.setData(new HashMap());
      // a.setTitle(item);           <------------- comment matters
      return a;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

Comment: It's probably related to what I said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71159519/incompatible-types-object-cannot-be-converted-to-diff/71252057#71252057. If you change your code to `a.setData(new HashMap<>());` it also compiles. After Java 8 this was probably improved, because it's definitely odd that losing generic information for `a` should lose generic information for the stream it's used in.

Comment: I'd guess it's a compiler bug (or perhaps unclear/imprecise specification). If you externalize that lambda to a class method, the comment becomes irrelevant. Seems obvious that the coincidence at source level happens to make the compiler look at unrelated raw types as affecting the stream.