# Migrate apache commons lang3 from 3.8.1 to 3.12.0 throws error incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Diff<?>

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-lang, apache-commons-lang3

I have this Java method which is used to compare data:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.Diff;

public void addChangedPositions(DiffrentResult diffrentResult , List<UpdatedPositionsData> updatedPositionsData) {
    for (Diff<?> diff : diffResult.getDiffs()) {
      UpdatedPositionsData updatedData = new UpdatedPositionsData();
      updatedData.setName(diff.getFieldName() == null ? null : diff.getFieldName());
      updatedData.setOldValue(diff.getLeft() == null ? null : diff.getLeft().toString());
      updatedData.setNewValue(diff.getRight() == null ? null : diff.getRight().toString());
      updatedPositionsData.add(updatedField);
    }    
  }
........

@Getter
@Setter
public class UpdatedPositionsData {

  private String name;
  private String oldValue;
  private String newValue;

}
```

With version `'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'` it's working fine.
But when I switch to version `implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'` I get error for this line `for (Diff<?> diff : diffResult.getDiffs()) {`

I get error:

```
incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Diff<?>
```

So I have:

```
Required type:
Object

Provided:
Diff
<?>
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I said in an answer to your other question, [incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Diff<?>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71159519/incompatible-types-object-cannot-be-converted-to-diff/71252057#71252057), that this occurs if you use raw types.

Now I've done some checking, and `DiffResult` has changed. In version 3.8.1 it wasn't a generic class: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.8.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/DiffResult.html. It was `Iterable<Diff<?>>`, but it had no generic type of its own. In version 3.10, it became generic: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.10/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/DiffResult.html.

My previous answer also shows the solution: use `DiffResult<?>`.